# Dynamically created combobox SelectedIndexChanged not adding controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to have panel displaying the result differently each time a user select items from pre-loaded combobox and dynamically created combobox.

Initially it will load a comboBox with item of ("HelloWorld"), each time when I do a SelectedIndexChanged with "HelloWorld", the panel will show 1.

However, problem lies on whenever I hit on add button and do SelectedIndexChanged with "HelloWorld" on the newly created button. It simply doesn't show 2 but instead when I hit on pre-loaded comboBox, it show 3.

Is it something to do with life-cycle events?

```
class form{
 int index = 0;
 private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button add = new Button();
        panel.Controls.Add(search());
        add.Click += new EventHandler((object o, EventArgs e) => { panel.Controls.Add(search()); });
        panel.Controls.Add(add);
    }
    
    public ComboBox search()
    {
        ComboBox searchField = new ComboBox();
        searchField.Items.Add("HelloWorld");
    
        searchField.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler((object io, EventArgs ie) =>
        {
            index++;
            Label display = new Label();
            display.Text = index.ToString();
            panel.Controls.Add(display);
        });

      return searchField;
    }
}
```

I have tried many days and couldn't understand it ... Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What control are you using as `panel` ?

Comment: Panel. It is created before runtime

Comment: Your code is not compiled. Please update it with working code.

Comment: It seems you need to define `index` as a property in Form instead of local varible in `search()`. Because whenever you hit click `index` is created with value `0`.

Comment: Yes. But that's not the reason. Also updated index variable

Comment: code is working fine..output in sequence 1,2,3 4..

Comment: yea. but it doesn't work after SelectedIndexChanged from a dynamically added "Add" button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int index { get; set; }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        index = 0;
        Button add = new Button();
        add.Text = "Add";
        add.Location = new Point(search().Location.X + search().Width + 10, search().Location.Y);
        panel.Controls.Add(search());
        add.Click += new EventHandler((object o, EventArgs e) => {
        panel.Controls.Add(search()); 
        });

        panel.Controls.Add(add);
    }
    public ComboBox search()
    {
        ComboBox searchField = new ComboBox();
        searchField.Items.Add("HelloWorld");
        searchField.Name = "cmb " + index.ToString();
        searchField.Location = new Point(10, (index + 1) * 20);
       
        searchField.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler((object io, EventArgs ie) =>
        {
            index++;
            Label display = new Label();
            display.Location = new Point(250, search().Location.Y-12);
            panel.Controls.Add(display);
            display.Text = index.ToString();
        });

        return searchField;
    }
```

Comment: This is the case when you add label dynamically... please make sure with the location of the control inside the panel. you are not mentioning location (x,y) which overlap the previous control....